# Push image from my website straight to master repo?

Tags: github, gitlab, git-push

Is it possible to `push` an image uploaded from my website straight to the `master` repo?
If it isn't, what's the best way to do this beside pushing it from console?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, as I am pretty sure whatever language you use, it has a way to run shell commands. Do you want that type of access given to your users? **Hell no!**

I would write a cron, that periodically checks a folder for new images, validate they are safe, then move them to your local git repo and push them (you can set trust between your computer and the master, so no need to use passwords.

Is this a good idea? **I do not think so**, What are you **really** trying to do?